# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova Error, MDAVSCLI failed with code 8

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I recently installed Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3 in Visual Studio 2013 running on Windows 8.1. I receive the following error when I try to run a standard new Cordova project (in the Android Emulator or Device). The project is named MyCordova01:

```
Error   20  cmd: Command failed with exit code 8    C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MyCordova01\MyCordova01\MDAVSCLİ  1   1   MyCordova01
```

Here is the build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyCordova01, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(97,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MyCordova01\MyCordova01>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.26 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\DXXQ5VLG.GQS\packages\vs-mda
1>MDAVSCLİ : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What could be the problem?
I already tried clearing the Cordova cache and running npm-install on the vs-mda directory.

**UPDATE:**
The [diagnostic build log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9711013/)

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you manage to solve it ?

Comment: Post the diagnostic build log. Go to Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run, change MSBuild project build output verbosity to Diagnostic. Rebuild the project and post the text from output window

Comment: The attached aapt.exe at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629 seems to fix the issue. Turns out that the problem is with the Android Build Tools.

Comment: I Solved removing accents from my files names.

Comment: I have the same error but not with android emulator, its with windows phone emulators, I installed windows sdk also, still same error. any clue?

MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD502: Error : BLD00502 : The Windows SDK is missing from your system. Please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513329 for system requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The attached aapt.exe at code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629 seems to fix the issue. Turns out that the problem is with the Android Build Tools.